# Own code on index.php wordpress theme file, help with the rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, custom-content

Hey there, I am sooo frustrated, asked and asked and can't seem to get an answer. Pleaseeeee help, I'll be very very clean whith my problem. I'll give hundreds of bears to the one who can help:)

1. I have a blog installed http://www.myblog.com - **it's part of a network, I use wordpress multisite**
2. **I created a table called cars** with 60 rows - **it's not a wordpress table**, it's my own custom table but I have created it inside the wordpress database.
3. On my blog theme, editing index.php, I display the records from the table **cars**, 10 rows per page and I write a custom pagination script with no relation what so ever with my wordpress pagination.
4. Now i have the following links: 
   www.myblog.com/index.php?currentpage=1
   www.myblog.com/index.php?currentpage=2
   and so on untill ... 
   www.myblog.com/index.php?currentpage=6
5. How can I rewrite them to pretty goole friendly links?

**Ideea one:** since they are not actually related to the wordpress blog, should I edit htaccess? I believe wordpress .htacces rules override any custom rules i put there... if you know a solution please share...

**Ideea two:** Tried to use wordpress rules and edited functions.php like so, with no luck:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' ); 
    function wpa5413_init() {     
        add_rewrite_rule(           
            '^/\?currentpage/(\d*)$',         
            'index.php?currentpage=$matches[1]',  
            'top' ); 
    }

    add_filter('query_vars', 'wpa3537_query_vars'); 
    function wpa3537_query_vars($query_vars) {     
        $query_vars[] = 'currentpage';     
        return $query_vars;
    }
```

**Please help me, honestly, I can even pay, I am soo frustraed... doing this work after my dayjob, it's been days of not sleeping, just need to make this happen, pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee**

PS don't vote down my question, i see others are struggeling with similar issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewrite rules must not start with the first slash, that is already stripped out. So the following code will add a rewrite rule that will set a query variable that we can later use:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse9016_init' );
function wpse9016_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( 'currentpage/(\d+)/?', 'index.php?wpse9016_currentpage=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
```

This query variable is ignored unless we add it to the list of *public query variables*:

```
add_action( 'query_vars', 'wpse9016_query_vars' );
function wpse9016_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'wpse9016_currentpage';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

After you have done this, you can check for it and do whatever you want when it is set. A common use is to load a specific template file:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse9016_template_include' );
function wpse9016_template_include( $template )
{
    if ( get_query_var( 'wpse9016_currentpage' ) ) {
        $template = locate_template( array( 'wpse9016_template.php' ) );
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Now, if you go to `http://www.example.com/currentpage/2/`, the file `wpse9016_template.php` in your theme directory will be loaded, where you can read `get_query_var( 'wpse9016_currentpage' )` to get the current page number.

Comment: Oh my god, you have no ideea how much i have struggled with this and I'm almost there, you are awesome, tyyyyyyyy, cheers! :) I have just one issue, on my index.page where I have the pagination links, the links won't be rewrited by the server. It's great if i type in my browser http://www.ezample.com/currentpage/2/, but on my index.php i still get http://www.example.com/?currentpage=2... Why? TY TY TY

Comment: @webmasters: You have to generate the new style of links yourself, WordPress does not do this for you (unlike other platforms with a complete routing system). What code do you currently use to write the pagination links?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of "pretty Google friendly links" do you mean exactly?

Rather than messing with the rewrite rules, it may be easier to move your custom code to a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), then add a new Page which uses that template, then set your site home page to that static page in Settings > Reading.

Again though - not sure what you want to have happen for the pagination. Sorry if I'm way off base in trying to help! :)

Comment: Something like: www.myblog.com/index.php?currentpage=1
turns into www.myblog.com/currentpage/1 or something like that, Ty sooo much

Comment: Well, if you use a Page with a custom template, you'll get to www.myblog.com/pagename just fine (assuming you have pretty Permalinks enabled in Settings > Permalinks). Since your pagination depends on the custom code you've written, you could then shorten it down at least so it would read www.myblog.com/pagename?p=1 etc. I don't think that Google will detract in any way for having that bit of pagination in the URL - it will just see /pagename.